# How does Facebook "like" button work? How to implement a plugin like it?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

Say I have a Facebook-like website with a high volume of traffic. Now I want to implement something like a Facebook "Like" plugin(?) for my site that other websites can use on their site. Let's call it "Hooray". How do I exactly implement one?

Or how does Facebook, Pinterest, etc. generally do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement your "Hooray" button you need to have components mentioned below:

1. A web service which will consumed by the client SDK to report that someone has ""Hoorayed" the post etc.
2. You need to have a database where you can store **who** "hoorayed" **what**.
3. You can consider every entry as a post or say "Hurricane".
4. Now every post is unique so you can identify who "Hoorayed" what.
5. Create a web service which tells the user who "Hoorayed" what.
6. Create a client SDK. It could be a JS library for web applications or Objective C framework for iOS etc. These client libraries will consume web services which are mentioned above.
7. Just like FB you will have to ask the consumer of your "Hooray" service to register an app on your platform. You can generate an appid for them and then all the data can be tagged with that.

Obviously these are just pointers and you can create a much sophisticated workflow based on your needs.

Answer (score -1):

If you go on the Facebook developers page, you can access the code for a Facebook "like" plugin in multiple languages and try to figure it out from there.

Comment: I don't think the OP is trying to figure out how to use the FaceBook plugin, but rather he wants to create one for himself.